# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module matchpoint due to:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the error message below when trying to run the ionic app after adding a new controller and html page to my existing ionic angular app. I've been debugging this for a few hours now and am stuck.

> ionic.bundle.js:8895 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module matchpoint due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   Failed to instantiate module settings.controller due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'settings.controller' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

I have made sure to add the 'settings.controller' as a dependency to my module definition in the app.js file.

***app.js file***

```
(function() {

    var matchpoint = angular.module('matchpoint', [
        'ionic','ionic.service.core',

        // Dashboard
        'dash.controller',

        // Authentication - Registration / Login
        'auth.controller',
        'auth.service',

        // Matches
        'match.controller',

        // Friends and Groups
        'friends.controller',
        'friends.service',
        'groups.service',

        // Communication
        'chat.controller',
        'chat.service',
        'email.service',

    // Settings
    'settings.controller',
...
```

***settings.controller.js file***

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('settings.controller', []);

  app.controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', 'authService', 'jsonService', 'config', 'utilityService', '$state', '$localStorage', 'friendsService', '$ionicPopup', 'mixpanelService', function($scope, authService, jsonService, config, utilityService, $state, $localStorage, friendsService, $ionicPopup, mixpanelService) {

  }]);

});
```

***settings.html***

```
<ion-view view-title="Settings" class="settings-view">

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">{{ passwordLabel }}</span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="{{ passwordPlaceholder }}" ng-model="user.oldPassword">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">New Password</span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Your new password" ng-model="user.newPassword">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="padding">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="done()">
        Done
      </button>
      <div class="error" ng-if="errorMessage" ng-bind="errorMessage">
      </div>
      <div class="error password-strength-error" ng-if="!passwordValid">
        Password must:
        <ul>
          <li>have at least 1 uppercase letter</li>
          <li>have at least 1 lowercase letter</li>
          <li>have at least 1 digit</li>
          <li>be at least 8 characters long</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
      <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-if="!isFirstPasswordChange"
              ui-sref="app.dashboard">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I should put this in a comment or an answer, but:

If you are running the ionic app with the `ionic serve` command, there is a good chance that you are running into a cache problem. I have run into a very similar problem. The index.html file is cached in your browser, and I'm guessing you added the reference to the `settings.controller.js` file in index. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Pawan. All other code changes were refreshing fine in the local instance when I used the "ionic serve -l" command but it seems this index.html is the one file that is cached. I had to go into chrome and then go into "all cookies and site data" to find data for the "localhost" url and then remove those. After that it worked fine. So it seems it wasn't a issue with the code I wrote but a nuance with running ionic locally with live reload.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with this

```
var app = angular.module('settings.controller', []);
```

The angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving So this one should be filled with value `ng-app`

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('ngApp Value', []);

  app.controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', 'authService', 'jsonService', 'config', 'utilityService', '$state', '$localStorage', 'friendsService', '$ionicPopup', 'mixpanelService', function($scope, authService, jsonService, config, utilityService, $state, $localStorage, friendsService, $ionicPopup, mixpanelService) {

  }]);

});
```

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand what you are referring to here. I have created other controllers with a similar syntax and the app worked fine. I don't use ng-app in my html files. I have the following defined in my app.js file.       // Settings
      .state('settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: 'features/settings/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
      })

Answer (score 0):

Your module 'matchpoint' depend on 'settings.controller' but it is not defined when you init (set) module 'matchpoint'. Ensure that **code for defining 'settings.controller' run before you define your main app: 'matchpoint'**

Put 'settings.controller.js'  before 'app.js' in your reference list should fix this error.

Comment: Hi Vu. In my index.html file I tried moving the script tag with settings.js above the script tag for app.js and I still receive the same error.

Comment: I see you are using bundle, look at bundle ordered file, if that, gulp-order allow you to handle order